# Python: libpython3.5.dylib not found?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, py2app

I would like to make a Mac executable for my Python code but always got this error message:

> OSError: Python library not found: .Python, libpython3.5.dylib, Python

Both PyInstaller and py2app returned the same error. What should I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: I'm working on figuring out a similar problem, but it would appear that Anaconda installs libpython3.6m.dylib (note the 'm'), which is just a build option when compiling Python.  I tried just creating a symlink to overcome this but my project still failed to build so I'm guessing this is why.  Not sure where to go next though.

Comment: @jamzsabb You are right. The 'm' matters, and now my project is working fine.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I gave up trying to build what I was building. Did you download another package or just symlink like I tried?

Comment: @jamzsabb No, I did not download any other package. I just created the executable using PyInstaller, py2app, or cxfreeze and then modified its Info.plist, changing libpython3.5.dylib to libpython3.5m.dylib.

Comment: it's py2app that is failing to build when I get this error actually haha.  It wasn't anything important luckily, just trying to build Spyder even though my current job mostly uses R.

Comment: Hi! I've run into the same problem as you and the same 'm' issue that @jamzsabb mentioned. Where exactly was this info.plist file that you modified? And what inside exactly did you modify?

Answer (score 11):

For Mac,  try rebuild python to generated shared lib using:

```sh
env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.5.x
```

as said in [pyenv offical doc](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#how-to-build-cpython-with---enable-shared)

in which `3.5.x` is version of python which you are using

For my here, after reinstall python:

```sh
env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.8.0
```

the dylib located in

`~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/libpython3.8.dylib`

which is soft link to 3.4MB file:

`~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Python`

Comment: This saved me, thanks